How to execute a hook only before "Given" step of BehaviorSpec KoTest DSL?
Consider the following test:
class BeforeHooksTest : BehaviorSpec({
    beforeContainer {
        println("Before-hook")
    }

    Given("Given - 1") {
        println("Given - 1")
        When("When - 1") {
            println("When - 1")
            Then("Then! - 1") {
                println("Then - 1")
            }
        }
    }
    Given("Given - 2") {
        println("Given - 2")
        When("When - 2") {
            println("When - 2")
            Then("Then! - 2") {
                println("Then - 2")
            }
        }
    }
})

the beforeContainer hook will execute before both: Given and When steps, because both of them are "containers". What is the DSL to configure my hook to be executed only before When?
For now, I came up to the following hacky solution:
beforeContainer {
    if (it.name.prefix == "Given: ") {
        println("Before-hook")
    }
}

